# Why the answer is different in two different methods for solving the same problem?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

Define a function $X$ thusly:
$$X(\theta) = \frac{A \sin \theta}{B \sin (\theta + 90^\circ)} \tag{1}$$
Evaluating at $\theta = 0^\circ$, we have

> $$X(0^\circ) = \frac{A \sin 0^\circ}{B \sin(0^\circ + 90^\circ)} = \frac{0}{B \sin 90^\circ} = \frac{0}{B} = 0 \tag{2}$$

Now, let's try this using ["phasor algebra"](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Phasor_algebra). A sinusoidal wave can be expressed as phasor, so the expression $(1)$ can be written as
$$X(\theta) = \frac{A\;\angle\theta}{B\;\angle( θ+90^\circ)}\tag{3}$$
which is
$$X(θ) = \frac{A}{B}\;\angle\left( \theta - \theta - 90^\circ\right) \tag{4}$$
where $A/B = |X(\theta)|$ is the magnitude of $X(\theta)$.
So $(4)$ becomes
$$X(\theta) = |X(\theta)| \angle( - 90^\circ) \tag{5}$$
Now, rewriting this expression in sinusoidal form gives
$$X(θ) = |X(\theta)| \sin(\theta - 90^\circ) \tag{6}$$
Now, evaluating *this* at $\theta = 0^\circ$ gives

> $$X(0^\circ) = |X(\theta)| \sin (0^\circ - 90^\circ) = |X(\theta)|\sin(-90^\circ) = -|X(\theta)|\tag{7}$$

My question:

> Why are the two values $X(0^\circ)$ different, when both methods are probably valid?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please consider taking the time to read the [faq] to familiarise yourself with some of our common practices. In addition, [this page](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/8348) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: I am sorry but, at least to me, this is almost impossible to read.

Comment: @user374723: I've attempted to convert your question into a more-readable form. I hope I've properly captured your meaning.

Comment: @user374723: Why did the $(-90^\circ)$ become $(\theta-90^\circ)$ in going from $(5)$ to $(6)$? (I double-checked that I copied your equation properly there.) Shouldn't $(6)$ simply be $|X(\theta)|\sin(-90^\circ)$, which would reduce to $-|X(\theta)|$ regardless of the value of $\theta$? (This is the first time I've ever seen phasors, by the way, so I don't really have any intuition about what things might be typographical errors.)

Answer (score 2):

Phasor algebra does not apply here. This is better explained using the complex representation.

You are computing $$\frac{A\sin\alpha}{B\sin\beta}$$ using the identities

$$\frac ABe^{i(\alpha-\beta)}=\frac{Ae^{i\alpha}}{Be^{i\beta}}=\frac{A\cos\alpha+iA\sin\alpha}{B\cos\beta+iB\sin\beta}.$$

These expressions do not match.

---

Said differenty,

$$\Im\frac uv\ne\frac{\Im u}{\Im v}.$$